# How to change styling of ring around input value - React-Select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I want to get rid of the ring around the cursor when on focus or when a value is selected/typed in and displayed in the select input box in my React-Select component. I'm able to change the styling of most of the component parts using [React-Select styles prop](https://react-select.com/styles#the-styles-prop) but not the ring.

I've tried changing the style of valueContainer that's part of the inner components as per the [docs](https://react-select.com/styles#inner-components) but that seems to be the parent container which includes the placeholder value etc.,

**What I've tried (in `styles`):**

```
// both with and without baseStyles

 valueContainer: (baseStyles, state) => ({
   ...baseStyles,
   border: "none",
 }),
 singleValue: (baseStyles, state) => ({
  ...baseStyles,
  borderColor: "green",
 }),
```

**My code:**

```
                  <Select
                    className="w-1/3 mr-1"
                    options={generateDayOptions()}
                    value={selectedDay}
                    onChange={(selectedDay) => setSelectedDay(selectedDay)}
                    placeholder="Day"
                    styles={{
                      control: (baseStyles, state) => ({
                        ...baseStyles,
                        borderColor: "#6b7280",
                        borderRadius: "0px",
                        outline: state.isFocused ? "none" : undefined,
                      }),
                    }}
                  />
```

Here's a snippet of the unwanted ring:
[image: unwanted ring]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the outline from the control component when it is hovered and remove its box-shadow styling:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const generateDayOptions = () => {
  return [{ value: 'Mon', label: 1 }];
};

export default function App() {
  const [selectedDay, setSelectedDay] = React.useState({
    value: 'Mon',
    label: 1,
  });

  return (
      <Select
        className="w-1/3 mr-1"
        options={generateDayOptions()}
        value={selectedDay}
        onChange={(selectedDay) => setSelectedDay(selectedDay)}
        placeholder="Day"
        styles={{
          control: (baseStyles, state) => {
            return {
              ...baseStyles,
              '&:hover': {
                outline: 'none',
              },
              boxShadow: 'none',
              borderColor: "#6b7280",
              borderRadius: "0px",
              outline: state.isFocused ? "none" : undefined,
            };
          },
        }}
      />
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey @Oluwafemi, still not working on my end. You mind sharing a codesandbox or something

Comment: Refer [here](https://react-dtdycf.stackblitz.io)

Comment: not working in local env.